# How do I edit this program that reads the average number of sets in the file and writes them to a new file?

Tags: c

I should write a program that reads a set of set of numbers from a file and performs the computation of mean, standard deviation on each set. After each computation it will write the computed values to a new file in c language

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char ch;

    FILE *fpr, *fpw;

    fpr = fopen("C:\\Users\\Hilal\\Desktop\\Data.txt", "r");

    if (fpr == NULL) {
        puts("Input file cannot be opened");
    }

    fpw = fopen("C:\\Users\\Hilal\\Desktop\\Output.txt", "w");

    if (fpw == NULL) {
        puts("Output file cannot be opened");
    }

    while (1) {
        ch = fgetc(fpr);
        if (ch == EOF)
            break;
        else

            fputc(ch, fpw);
    }

    fclose(fpr);
    fclose(fpw);

    return 0;
}
```

I have no problem opening or writing the file. but I'm having trouble getting the set of numbers written on each line in the file one by one and dealing with each line separately.Like

**Input:** `4 47 -5 12 44/ 2 128 -127/ 1 17/`

**Output:** `20.4 23.7/ 1 127.5/ 9 11.3/`

Comment: improved formatting

Answer (score 0):

The code you have provided echos the text from your input file to your output file. It does this character by character. What you're trying to do is go through your input file line by line. If you know how many numbers are on each input line, you could use a function like fscanf.

You can find usage examples [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_fscanf.htm) or, if you have access to a terminal, type in `man fscanf`.